# Call a method on every word in NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I would like to loop through an `NSString` and call a custom function on every word that has certain criterion (For example, "has 2 'L's"). I was wondering what the best way of approaching that was. Should I use Find/Replace patterns? Blocks?

```
-(NSString *)convert:(NSString *)wordToConvert{
    /// This I have already written
    Return finalWord;
}

-(NSString *) method:(NSString *) sentenceContainingWords{
    // match every word that meets the criteria (for example the 2Ls) and replace it with what convert: does. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways I know of looping an array that will work for you are as follows:

```
NSArray *words = [sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

for (NSString *word in words)
{
    NSString *transformedWord = [obj method:word];
}
```

and

```
NSArray *words = [sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

[words enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id word, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSString *transformedWord = [obj method:word];
}];
```

The other method, `–makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`, won't work for you. It expects to be able to call `[word method:obj]` which is backwards from what you expect.

Comment: For some languages like Chinese, Japanese, German, whitespace is not obvious limiter between words, hence Ken approach is the proper one.

Answer (score 20):

To enumerate the words in a string, you should use `-[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` with `NSStringEnumerationByWords` and `NSStringEnumerationLocalized`. All of the other methods listed use a means of identifying words which may not be locale-appropriate or correspond to the system definition. For example, two words separated by a comma but not whitespace (e.g. "foo,bar") would not be treated as separate words by any of the other answers, but they are in Cocoa text views.

```
[aString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])
                            options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
    if ([substring rangeOfString:@"ll" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        /* do whatever */;
}];
```

As documented for `-enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`, if you call it on a mutable string, you can safely mutate the string being enumerated *within the `enclosingRange`*. So, if you want to replace the matching words, you can with something like `[aString replaceCharactersInRange:substringRange withString:replacementString]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you could write your criteria with regular expressions, then you could probably do a regular expression matching to fetch these words and then pass them to your `convert:` method.

You could also do a split of string into an array of words using `componentsSeparatedByString:` or `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`, then go over the words in the array and detect if they fit your criteria somehow. If they fit, then pass them to `convert:`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 12/macOS 10.14 the recommended way to do this is with the [Natural Language framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage).

For example:

```swift
import NaturalLanguage

let myString = "..."

let tokeniser = NLTokenizer(unit: .word)
tokeniser.string = myString

tokeniser.enumerateTokens(in: myString.startIndex..<myString.endIndex) { wordRange, attributes in
    performActionOnWord(myString[wordRange])
    return true // or return false to stop enumeration
}
```

Using `NLTokenizer` also has the benefit of allowing you to optionally specify the language of the string beforehand:

```swift
tokeniser.setLanguage(.hebrew)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a while loop to go through the string like this.

```
NSRange spaceRange = [sentenceContainingWords rangeOfString:@" "];
NSRange previousRange = (NSRange){0,0};
do {
   NSString *wordString;
   wordString = [sentenceContainingWord substringWithRange:(NSRange){previousRange.location+1,(spaceRange.location-1)-(previousRange.location+1)}];
   //use the +1's to not include the spaces in the strings
   [self convert:wordString];
   previousRange = spaceRange;
   spaceRange = [sentenceContainingWords rangeOfString:@" "];
} while(spaceRange.location != NSNotFound);
```

This code would probably need to be rewritten because its pretty rough, but you should get the idea.

Edit: Just saw Jacob Gorban's post, you should definitely do it like that.